# Undefined control sequence in first line of fontspec.sty

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontawesome, cv

I am creating a CV in LaTeX. The below code is a MWE (example.tex):

```
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[paper=letterpaper,fontsize=10pt]{article}                % KOMA-article class

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                               % Enable pdflatex (had [pdftex])
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}                           % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
%   \textheight=700px                                   % Saving trees ;-) 
\usepackage{url}                                        % Clickable URL's
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                    % Wrap text along figures
\frenchspacing                                  % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}                               % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FOR ICONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontspec}       %Github, mail, etc icons
\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path = fonts/]{fontawesome-webfont}
\def\faLinux{{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}}
\def\faSE{{\FA\symbol{"F18D}}}
\def\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\def\github{{\FA\symbol{"F092}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
\usepackage{sectsty}                            % Custom sectioning (see below)
\sectionfont{%                                  % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%                   % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}
    }

%%% Macros
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}              % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}           % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}

\newcommand{\EdEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill                    % Study
        \colorbox{Black}{%
            \parbox{6em}{%
            \hfill\color{White}#2}} \par                % Duration
        \textit{#3} \par        % School
        \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\ResearchEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill                    % Study
        \colorbox{Black}{%
            \parbox{6em}{%
            \hfill\color{White}#2}} \par                % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par                  % School
         \noindent \small #4    % Description
        \normalsize \par}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\noindent \colorbox{Black}{\parbox{4em} \hfill \color{White} \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} FIRST NAME}
\newline
\noindent \colorbox{Black}{\parbox{4em} \hfill \color{White} \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} LAST NAME}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FOR ICONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Linux icon: \faLinux \\
StackExchange icon: \faSE \\
GitHub icon: \github \\
Skype icon: \faSkype
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% Education ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Education}{}
\EdEntry{Ph.D. \hspace{1mm} Major: Major Name}{Then-Now}{\hspace{11.5mm} School Name}
\EdEntry{B.S. \hspace{4mm} Major: Major Name}{Then1-Then2}{\hspace{13.5mm} School Name}

%%% Research Experience --------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{Experience}{}
\ResearchEntry{Job Title I}{Time I}{Place I}{Here I am describing my experience}
\ResearchEntry{Job Title II}{Time II}{Place II}{I will describe my experience here}

%%% References ------------------------------------------------------------
\NewPart{References}{}
Available upon request
\end{document}
```

The CV can be generated using "pdflatex example.tex" as long as two blocks of lines (15-21 and 63-66) are commented out. In the example above, these blocks are surrounded by comment signs with the term "FOR ICONS".

I am trying to add a few symbols to my CV (GitHub, Skype, etc). These symbols are from the FontAwesome package. All the code related to adding these symbols is in the previously-mentioned two line blocks. Hence, these two line-blocks are causing the problem.

When I try to run "xelatex example.tex", I get an error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 {\rtf
         1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265\cocoasubrtf210
```

When I look in my fontspec.sty script (located in /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/), I see that the undefined control sequence is the first line.

I should say that I created the fontspec.sty file by copy-pasting everything from this link (http://chocolatshalba.ch/files/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty) into a text file, and saving it as .sty into the directory shown above.

I have been working on this problem for several hours, and am at a loss. You may gather that I am not too familiar with how the .sty files work! Thank you for any advice; it might help me get a job!...

Comment: You seem to have saved fontspec as rtf-file. Instead of copying the file  manually install the package with the tools of your texsystem (but it shoul be in texlive 2014 anyway)

Comment: Do not copy the `.sty` from the first place you happen to come across it! A normal TeX Live 2014 installation will have it, and in a newer version than the random one you found. If it does not, then there are bigger problems with your installation that need to be addressed. And **never** install files yourself into `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist`. It may be that you overwrote the actual file your system already had. There are other places for installing your own files. (And many questions here about what to do with 'personal' `.sty` files.)

Comment: @jon thank you! Do you mean if I download "Tex Live 2014", it will have the .sty file I need? Is there a way for me to see if I even have Tex Live 2014? I am thinking that might be the better approach, because I cannot find the fontspec.sty file anywhere else...

Comment: You do have TL 2014: if you look in the error line you posted, you'll see: "(/usr/local/texlive/ **2014** /texmf-dist/...". You should have `fontspec` installed, though it depends on how you got TeX Live in the first place, which remains unclear. However, note that, for the most part, and certainly until you know what you are doing, you should rely on your official distribution and what is available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/?lang=en).

Comment: @jon. thank you! I've been looking through CTAN (after reading about it on other sites). I could not find fontspec.sty on it. So, can I clarify, are you suggesting that I download TL 2014 from CTAN (because maybe what I downloaded before was not adequate)?

Comment: @jon. Also, I am using a Mac, so I notice there is also MacTex. I am thinking of downloading from here (https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html), which came from CTAN website.  It is supposed to include TexLive.

Comment: MacTeX is (I think) the best choice for Macs, but I have never used it. It is, however, the Mac version of TeX Live. FYI, `fontspec` is available on CTAN [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), but you have to know to generate the `.sty` from the `.dtx` file, or install directly the `.tds.zip` file (which is the easiest option). I'd advise installing MacTeX. Get the 2015 version, of course!

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a direct answer to your question, but you can access the icons of FontAwesome directly with the package `fontawesome` you are loading. Just the macro names are partly different.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FOR ICONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Linux icon: \faLinux \\
StackExchange icon: \faStackExchange \\
GitHub icon: \faGithub \\
Skype icon: \faSkype
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Loading the font manually via fontspec and creating macros is redundant. So just remove the lines 16-21, use the right macro names and you should be fine.

Comment: I downloaded MacTex 2015, and then followed your suggestions. I believe downloading this helped my problem (in terms of the fontspec.sty file being appropriately configured). However, I did use your changes (because it seems like a more direct way), but I get an error when I run lulatex example.tex "Undefined control sequence. l.145 \faLinux". Strangely, if I change \faLinux with \faTwitter, then I get a twitter symbol! Any idea why \faLinux would not work, while \faTwitter would? Thank you again!

Comment: Did you also update all the packages to the latest version? Just start the program `TeX Live Utility` which was installed alongside MacTeX and select `Actions > Update All Packages` in the menubar to do so.